# Meaning to a sentence-

Tags: sentence-meaning

While traveling to the spa's remote location could be hectic, visitors to the spa more than made up for the stress by unwinding in a supremely Pacific environment.

I found this sentence structure very difficult to understand. Please describe it and suggest me how to get this type of sentence structure for practice?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it makes no sense to say that **visitors** *more than made up for the stress*. While it's *possible* to interpret it in this way it's highly improbable.

It's far more likely that the sentence is simply poorly constructed (and it is, regardless of anything else). This is also seen by the awkward construction in the final part of the sentence that ties into that confusing use of *visitors*.

---

I would make a few edits, including correcting this main issue. Note that, in my version, I add a phrase in square brackets only to aid comprehension, not because the sentence needs it.

> ✘ While traveling to the spa's remote location could be hectic, **visitors** to the spa more than made up for the stress by unwinding in a supremely Pacific environment.
>
> ✔ **Although travel** to the spa's remote location could be hectic, **the spa itself** more than made up for **any** stress [in getting there] by **allowing visitors to unwind** in a supremely Pacific environment.

Note, too, that this is a past-tense statement. If it means to describe something in the present, then it should be ***can*** *be hectic* and *more than* ***makes*** *up*.

Comment: I feel this types of sentences very hard to understand and I want you to suggest me materials to be perfect with these types of sentences. Also reading only doesn't help, getting it's explanation helps the most.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking out or removing some words may clarify the structure.

While [traveling to the spa's remote location] could be hectic, visitors [to the spa] [more than] made up for the stress by unwinding in [a supremely Pacific] environment.

While traveling could be hectic, causing stress, the visitors more than made up for the stress by unwinding in the environment.

A supremely Pacific environment is a very pleasant one.

Comment: Just a thought - surely "a supremely **p**acific environment" would be a peaceful and pleasant one, but "a supremely **P**acific environment" would inevitably have elephant seals, squalls, volcanoes and perhaps the odd island of plastic litter at its centre?

Answer (score 0):

While traveling to the spa's remote location could be hectic, visitors to the spa more than made up for the stress by unwinding in a supremely Pacific environment.

Another example:

While doing his difficult homework, the student more than made up for his effort by relaxing in his living room afterwards.

**While** here is not during, it means: **although**

The main difficulty for an ELLer is the expression: ** more than make up for something**.

That phrase has two parts:

1) to make up for something = an idiom which means to compensate for something, make a negative into something neutral.

As in:

**Your apology to me **makes up for** your being rude to me**. [neutralizes the rudeness]

2) **more than make up for something**, goes a step further.

**Your apology to me **more than makes up for** your being rude to me**. [Here the apology goes further than neutralizing the rudeness, it makes the situation positive.]

These types of idioms (make up for something) need to be learned by heart. It is these idioms that make English so tricky.